# AS3 MovieClip click event not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm working on a flash slider using as3 and cannot get the click event to fire which clicked on a MovieClip.

The click event works perfectly when targeting the stage but not any MC.

Below is all the code in the project.

The part in question is toward the bottom of **SLIDER.as**

```
canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.canvasClick);
```

The stage and library are both empty. Thank you in advance.

PS: I'm pretty new to flash.

**MAIN.AS**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;


public class Main extends MovieClip {

    public function Main() {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init)
    }

    private function init(e:Event){
        var images:Array = new Array("./media/engines/Engines-1.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-2.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-3.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-4.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-5.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-6.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-7.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-8.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-9.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-10.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-11.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-12.jpg", "./media/engines/Engines-13.jpg");
        var slider:Slider = new Slider(stage, images);          
    }
}

}
```

**SLIDER.AS**

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Slider extends MovieClip {

    private var images:Array;
    private var STAGE:Stage;

    private var stageWidth:Number;
    private var stageHeight:Number;
    private var centerX:Number;
    private var centerY:Number;
    private var tsHeight:Number = 100;
    private var tsPadding:Number = 10;


    public function Slider(stageGlobal, imageConfig:Array) {
        this.STAGE = stageGlobal;
        this.images = imageConfig;

        this.stageWidth = this.STAGE.stageWidth;
        this.stageHeight = this.STAGE.stageHeight;

        this.centerX    = this.stageWidth / 2;
        this.centerY = this.stageHeight / 2;

        this.createCanvas();
    }

    public function createCanvas():void {
        // SLIDER HOLDER
        var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        canvas.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.stageWidth, this.stageHeight, 15, 15);
        canvas.opaqueBackground = 0xDDDDDD;
        canvas.mouseEnabled = true;
        this.STAGE.addChild(canvas);


        // HEADER / TITLE HOLDER
        var header:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        header.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.stageWidth, 40, 15, 15);
        header.opaqueBackground = 0x000000;

        canvas.addChild(header);


        // FOOTER ACTION HOLDER
        var footer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        footer.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, this.stageHeight - 40, this.stageWidth, 40, 15, 15);
        footer.opaqueBackground = 0x000000;

        canvas.addChild(footer);

        // THUMBSTRIP HOLDER
        var thumbstrip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        thumbstrip.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, this.stageHeight - 160, this.stageWidth, 120, 15, 15);
        thumbstrip.opaqueBackground = 0x555555;

        canvas.addChild(thumbstrip);

        canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, this.canvasClick);
    }

    private function canvasClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
        trace(e);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It probably has to do with the way you're drawing your MovieClips.

From the docs: "The opaque background region does not respond to mouse events."

Try drawing rectangles like this:

```
        // SLIDER HOLDER
        var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
        canvas.graphics.beginFill(0xDDDDDD);
        canvas.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.stageWidth, this.stageHeight, 15, 15);
        canvas.graphics.endFill();
        canvas.mouseEnabled = true;
        this.STAGE.addChild(canvas);
```

Comment: My thought as well.  @AhmadAmin - Did you try this?

Comment: This was the solution to the problem. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Event after slider added to stage so in the slider class you need to write

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Slider extends MovieClip {

        private var images:Array;
        private var STAGE:Stage;

        private var stageWidth:Number;
        private var stageHeight:Number;
        private var centerX:Number;
        private var centerY:Number;
        private var tsHeight:Number = 100;
        private var tsPadding:Number = 10;


        public function Slider(stageGlobal, imageConfig:Array) {

            this.STAGE = stageGlobal;
            this.images = imageConfig;
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added);

        }

        public function added(e:Event)
        {


            this.stageWidth = this.STAGE.stageWidth;
            this.stageHeight = this.STAGE.stageHeight;

            this.centerX    = this.stageWidth / 2;
            this.centerY = this.stageHeight / 2;

            this.createCanvas();
        }

        public function createCanvas():void {
            // SLIDER HOLDER
            var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            canvas.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.stageWidth, this.stageHeight, 15, 15);
            canvas.opaqueBackground = 0xDDDDDD;
            canvas.mouseEnabled = true;
            this.STAGE.addChild(canvas);


            // HEADER / TITLE HOLDER
            var header:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            header.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, 0, this.stageWidth, 40, 15, 15);
            header.opaqueBackground = 0x000000;

            canvas.addChild(header);


            // FOOTER ACTION HOLDER
            var footer:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            footer.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, this.stageHeight - 40, this.stageWidth, 40, 15, 15);
            footer.opaqueBackground = 0x000000;

            canvas.addChild(footer);

            // THUMBSTRIP HOLDER
            var thumbstrip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
            thumbstrip.graphics.drawRoundRect(0, this.stageHeight - 160, this.stageWidth, 120, 15, 15);
            thumbstrip.opaqueBackground = 0x555555;

            canvas.addChild(thumbstrip);

            canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, canvasClick);
        }

        private function canvasClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
            trace(e);
        }

    }

}
```

I hope it would help :)

Comment: Thank you for taking a look.

this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, added); is not being fired and doesn't give an error either.

Comment: I tried without this and also this.STAGE.addEventListener and none is working.

I also tried canvas.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, func) which is working but the MouseEvent.CLICK still isn't working event after that is fired.

Comment: Adding the click event listener before/after being added to stage would have the same end result.  Your answer won't actually change the behavior at all.